# Email reply from interviewer after sending thank you email

Tags: interviewing

I sent a thank you email to a job interviewer and within an hour of sending it, he replied thanking me for coming in to talk to him and said he will get in touch with me 'soon'.  Does that mean anything or is he just being courteous?

Comment: Just courteous. Very courteous. Maybe this person is a "inbox-zero" kind of person. The interviewer is not the one making the hiring decision in most cases, even though their opinion may influence it. 'Soon' translates as 'whenever my boss, HR, and some other suits can agree on something and pick a candidate.

Comment: It means the interviewer is polite and nice. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

> I sent a thank you email to a job interviewer

That is a good initiative to thank you interviewer. It shows your interest.

> he replied thanking me for coming in to talk to him and said he will get in touch with me 'soon'.

It is just being courteous but it is a good sign that he took the time to send you an email. You cannot get any conclusion from that e-mail. Only time will tell you how the interview went.